# CRC Craking knowing result

Tags: java, c, security, crc

I have a CRC code probably CRC-8 (or greater but truncated) because it is 1 byte long, but I don't know how it has been calculated. I also have the data (4 byte long) used to calculate it. Is there any way to reverse or brute force the algorithm and the parameters? I tried several solutions, without being able to find the polynomial used to calculate it.
Thank you very much, bye.

Comment: Logically, there is an infinite number of possible solutions.

Comment: You could find the simplest solution which produces this `byte` and guess this is right.  There is no guarantee of success.  DO you have any really short examples to work from?

Comment: Sure, I have 0x98014443 that produces 0x38, or 0x98014411 that produces 0xE7. I know that there could be infinte solutions using a single CRC code, but using more then 1 the number of possibility should be 1 after some tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CRC RevEng](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/) to try to reverse engineer the CRC.  It will check for common CRCs first, and see if your string and CRC match one of those.  If it does, then you've likely found it.  If not, then you will need several more examples to reverse engineer the polynomial, bit ordering, and pre and post processing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I am trying it now. Unfortunately with 2 values it works, but using 3 or 4 values it is not able to find the result. I can provide more example, unfortunately for the moment I have only 4 values: 0x98014411:0xe7,  0x98014443:0x38, 0x97091376:0xe6, 0x98015015:0x58

Comment: How do you know it's a CRC?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not 100% sure. I spooked with a person that studied the system and it confirmed me that with high probability it is a CRC. However unfortunately I am reversing engineering a proprietary solution I cannot be totally sure about it. Do you think it is not a CRC? I add a new sample: 0x98014423:0xa8. Tkx

Comment: It may not be.  The first check is to find the CRCs of three strings such that two of the strings when exclusive-or'ed give the third string.  Then see if the exclusive-or of the CRC's of the first two gives the CRC of the third.  If not, then you know you don't have a CRC.  If it does, then you might have a CRC or part of a CRC.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you suggest. Unfortunately I can not have these three strings because my string are always numbers one near the other. Is there any other way to test if it is a CRC or if it is not? If it is not a CRC do you have any suggestion on what could it be.. Tks

Comment: How about four strings?  (A^B)^(C^D) == 0.  So A can be close to B and C can be close to D.  If the same operation on the check values does not give zero, then you can rule out a CRC.

Comment: Thanks, today I had been able to perform both tests using:           97091376 CRC: E6 and 00000001 CRC:A7 to find a third string with a valid CRC. While for the second experiment I used: A= 98014429 CRC:B3 B=98014427  CRC:A6 C=98014438 CRC=14 D=98014436 CRC:01. Is there any way to recover the algorithm and polynomial used to compute them? Using reveng unfortunately I had no luck. Tks again

Comment: [(A^B=0X11)^(C^D=0X11)]=0X00 ; [(CRC(A)^CRC(B)=A7)^(CRC(C)^CRC(D)=A7)] = 0x00;

Comment: Ok, you probably have a CRC or part of a CRC.  Now I would use reveng to compute some common CRCs of various lengths, and see if any of those correlate to your 8-bit check value.  So try not only 8-bit CRC's, but also 16-bit and 32-bit CRCs and look at the two and four bytes of those to see if any match.  Look at both the check byte normally and its bit reversal.

Comment: I tried with -c and -v with 97091376 using all available algorithms from CRC-8 to CRC-82/DARC and I found a couple of correlation. After using the same program I tested 98014429, but I did not found same correlation. Now I also wrote a program able to compute all combination of XOR, Init polynomial value in with all different parameters.. but at the moment looks like the time to compute all the possibility will be too long.. :( Is there any other possibility? It is for my master thesis. Tkx

Comment: If the message is always four bytes, then instead of figuring out the CRC, you can solve for the linear equation over GF(2) and generate the check values that way.  What you would generate is a 8x32 matrix of bits to multiply the four bytes by, and an 8-bit value to exclusive-or the result with.  Think mx + b.  The matrix "multiplication" in this case is anding each row of the matrix with the four bytes and exclusive-oring together those 32 bits to get one bit of the eight bit result.  Repeat for the other seven rows.

Comment: You can consider all of those matrix and vector components to be variables to solve for over GF(2).  Then find enough cases to be able to solve the simultaneous equations.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I will refresh the matrix theory, in order to understand better your suggest. Thanks again